# Rename Form using xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, odoo

I want to change name of form 'Opportunities', I tried this code but nothing is working

```
<xpath expr="//form[@string='Opportunities']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name ="string">Affaire</attribute>
        </xpath>
```

Comment: Do you have the base xml?

Comment: Do you need to change the menu string because tge string of form has no effect on the UI

Comment: i want to change name of form not menuitem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using new api, then jinja is updated and you cant xpath using string.
so you should use the name or other attributes of form.
Also the form string name is actually

```
<form string="Merge Leads/Opportunities">
```

you should Xpath like below:

```
if you are using version 8
<xpath expr="//form[@string='Merge Leads/Opportunities']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name ="string">Affaire</attribute>
</xpath>
```

else case

```
<xpath expr="//form" position="attributes">
            <attribute name ="string">Affaire</attribute>
</xpath>
```

Just be ensure you have inherited the correct id as "merge_opportunity_form"